# consulta con Linq usando cláusulas WHERE IN y ORDER BY

Tags: c#, sql

Mostrar los **clientes** que pertenecen a las **regiones** **CA, MT o WA**, ordenados por región ascendentemente y por nombre descendentemente.

```
CODE SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Region IN(‘CA’, ‘MT’, ‘WA’)
ORDER BY Region, CompanyName DESC
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, ¿has intentado algo? Si nos muestras tu código sería un buen comienzo para orientarte en el código que deseas transformar a Linq ;)

Comment: Expression<Func<Customers , bool>> predcostumer = c =>  (c.region== b || c.region== x || c.region== a);

Comment: b,x,a son las regiones asignadas a variables

Comment: || estaba ocupando este operador(or ) pero  si un custumers se encuentra en varias regiones por el operador or solo muestra la ultima

Comment: @CarlosHernandezLopez **[edit] la pregunta con lo que haya intentado**. Los comentarios son temporales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tenga un `DbContext()` con un `DbSet<Customers>`, yo lo haria de la siguiente manera:

```
using(EjemploContex db = new EjemploContex()){

     //Lamba
     var customersList = db.Customers.Where(x => x.Region == ("CA" || "MT" || "WA")).OrderBy(x => x.Region).OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyName).ToList();

     //Query
     var customersList2 = (from customerin db.Customers
                     where customer.Region == ("CA" || "MT" || "WA")
                     select customer)
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Region)
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyName)
                     .ToList();

 }
```

Comment: Si claro, deja lo modfico